# Checking user input before assinging it in VB

Tags: vb.net, variable-assignment

How would you check if an input is valid before assigning it to a variable. For instance, if I had this:

```
Dim Number As Integer
Number = Console.ReadLine()
```

If someone were to input something that wasn't numeric, it would throw an invalid case exception. This can of course be solved with a try/catch but I have been told that using them is bad practice. Also, if I were to use IsNumeric(), I would still need to store the input, risking another cast error before even managing to check if it is numerical or not. What would the best way to go about this be?

Comment: Use one of the `TryParse` methods.

Comment: I recommend to start using Option Strict On.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TryParse`.  To use your example:

```
Dim Number As Integer

If Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), Number) Then
    ' Logic for the successful conversion
Else
    ' Logic for the unsuccessful conversion
End If
```

If the conversion is successful, `TryParse` will return True and the value will be in the out parameter (Number).  If the conversion is unsuccessful, `TryParse` will return false and the Number (the out parameter) will be 0.

Here's more information on [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1); several other data types also have a `TryParse` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Console.ReadLine method returns a String so using an Integer variable would not be good.
A hint is to always check the documentation, or the intellisense, to get the type of the returned value.

The following will read the value to a String variable, and the use the Integer.TryParse method to parse it to an Integer.

```
Dim strNumber As String
Dim iNumber as Integer
strNumber = Console.ReadLine()
If Not Integer.TryParse(strNumber, iNumber) Then
  'Handle error
End If
```